# Building the appropriate SQL queries for a web from, when order doesn't matter

Tags: python, sql, forms, sqlite, flask

I will read the input into the following web form:

[image]

via Flask thus:

```
def query():
    if request.method == "POST":
        job_title_input = request.form['title']
        description_operator = request.form['DescriptionOperator']
        description_input = request.form['description']
        salary_operator = request.form['SalaryOperator']
        salary_input = request.form['salary']
        location_input = request.form['location']
```

The values received will be used to query this table in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE scrapedjobs
             (id integer primary key autoincrement not null,
             huburl text,
             business_name text,
             location text,
             jobtitle text,
             description text,
             joburl text,
             salary int,
             date_first_scraped date)
```

It's my first time attempting to handle of the permutations in a web form's submission, and after cascading down through just the first two fields, I can see already that it's is getting convoluted:

```
    base_query = """SELECT * FROM scrapedjobs"""
    if job_title_input != '':
        base_query = base_query + """ WHERE jobtitle IN ('""" + job_title_input + """')"""
        job_title_input_flag = """ AND"""
    else:
        job_title_input_flag = """"""

    if description_input != '':
        if job_title_input_flag != '':
            base_query = base_query + """ AND description """ + description_operator + " " + "('" + description_input + "')"
            description_input_flag = """ AND"""
        else:
            base_query = base_query + """ WHERE description """ + description_operator + " " + "('" + description_input + "')"
            description_input_flag = """ AND"""
    else:
        description_input_flag = """"""
```

The further down I go, the more nesting of if/else's will be needed, and it's not sustainable if new fields are added to the form. A major flaw also is that I'm setting things up whereby each field depends on whether the previous fields had a value, and so on. The reality of course is that in a straight query like this without grouping or joins or the like, **order is irrelevant**, once I can take care of when I need `AND` (in case a field did have a value) and when I need instead `WHERE`. Worse still, I will have to parameterize all of this when I pass it to `cursor.execute()` in `sqlite3`.

I'm not the first person to every read in values from a multiple form and build appropriate `SELECT`s - what patterns or more efficient techniques can I take advantage of?

Answer (score 2):

I've been there and I know how it will end. Manually constructing the queries like in your case is highly error-prone, not readable and leads to supporting nightmares. Instead, look into abstracting things away with [`sqlalchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [`flask-sqlalchemy`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/) specifically.  With SQLAlchemy you can compose queries in pieces and it will build the final query correctly.

As a real world example, study the [Flask Mega-Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) (`sqlalchemy` is used in [chapter 4](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) and later).